# Is There a Best Way to Chunk a String from the last element to first

Tags: kotlin, split, chunks

Is there a good or best way to add some leading zeros for the string chunk that don't have an appropriate number of digits. At the code below I want to split a string where each chunk is composed of 4 digits.

To add some leading zeros to a string I use this approach:

```kt
val text = "1010111".reversed()  // 1110101 | len: 7
  .chunked(4) {  // [1110, 101 *this element only gets 3 digits]
    val sb = StringBuilder(it)
    val rem = it.length % 4  // 3

    /* [1110, 1010 -> now this element have a same digits w...] */
    if (rem != 0) sb.append("0".repeat(4 - rem)).toString()

  } // result: [1110, 1010]
  .reversed() // [1010, 1110]
  .map { it.reversed } // [0101, 0111]

val result = text.joinToString("")
println("""
   before: $text    /*  101 0111 */
   after : $result  /* 0101 0111 */
""".trimIndent())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would probably be the simplest approach:

```
val text  = "1010111"

val result = text
    .reversed()
    .chunked(4)
    .joinToString("") { it.padStart(4, '0') }
    .reversed()
```

`reverse()` does what the name implies

`chunked(4)` gives us multiple list with 4 elements each. The last list might have
less than 4 if the initial text is not divisible by 4

`joinToString("")` let's us put the thing together, while also applying the next modifier:

`it.padStart(4, '0')` adds as many '0' as necessary in order for the current chunk to be 4 characters long (basically it will only add to the final chunk

`reverse()` returns our text back in the correct order.

Comment: In the **joinToString("")** I think it should to use **padEnd()** rather than **padStart()**, because the bit is reversed. Btw your code is very clean sir, I think I will use your solution, thanks.

Comment: This is indeed an easy-to-read, maintainable solution. (It creates quite a number of temporary objects, though.)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```kotlin
    val text = "1010111" // len: 7
    val zerosToAdd = (4 - text.length % 4).takeIf { it != 4 } ?: 0 // 1
    val result = "0".repeat(zerosToAdd) + text // result = 01010111
```

Comment: This solution is likely to be much more efficient than the others, as it creates only a couple of temporary objects. (It's a little more involved and harder to read, though. Them's the breaks, as someone once said…) If you wanted ultimate efficiency, maybe you could use `buildString` (or a manual `StringBuilder`) and manually add all the leading zeroes and then the text, to avoid the temporary string returned by `repeat()`.

Answer (score 0):

[chunked](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html) can also take a second argument, a function in which you can transform the chunk. In this case it needs to be reversed and then in the *let* lambda leading zeros can be prepended with [padStart](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/pad-start.html):

```
val text = "1010111"

val result = text
  .reversed()
  .chunked(4) { chunk -> chunk.let { if (it.length < 4) it.padEnd(4, '0') else it } }
  .reversed()
  .joinToString("") { it.reversed() }

println(result)   // Output: [0101, 0111]
```

Comment: You can drop the `if`, `padStart` already handles that for you: `chunk.reversed().padStart(4, '0')`

Comment: That is correct. But: I quickly benchmarked it and it would be slower to directly call _padStart_. About 10% slower for the short text of the OP. For texts of 50 characters it becomes 15% slower, and for texts of 100 characters it becomes 25% slower, etc. So to call _padStart_ on every _it_ can become expensive depending on the amount of chunks.

Comment: @lukas.j how did you benchmark this? And on which Kotlin target platform? Microbenchmarking has many many pitfalls, so it's hard to do it correctly. Even if this performance issue were confirmed, it doesn't mean it's important in the current context, and should probably be investigated only when it becomes an actual problem. If you really want to mention performance aspects in this answer, put the simple code first and explain what could be changed for optimal performance separately

Comment: I think you're missing a `reversed()` before `chunked(4)`

Comment: @Joffrey The whole thing I posted was wrong, by coincidence it gave the correct result. I edited code. Thanks.

Comment: @Lukas.j, it need more than 5 functions, is this still the best way sir?

Comment: @Joffrey I'm aware of the problems of benchmarking. When I do it quick for things like that (and always on the JVM), I build a large list of random inputs – 100000 in this case – and then I do _measureTimeMillis { for each item in list exec the code }_.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to reversing the string and chunking it and pad the last element and reverse back, would be to just calculate the padding needed at the beginning of the string:

```
fun String.padStartWithZerosToMultipleOf(value: Int): String {
  return this.padStart(length.div(value) * value + length.rem(value).let { if (it == 0) 0 else value }, '0')
}

val text = "1010111"

val result = text.padStartWithZerosToMultipleOf(4)

println(result)
```